# Formatted Text and Popovers in iOS4

Tags: objective-c, ios4, text-formatting, popover

I'm working on a prototype app that has a challenging behavior. I thought I'd ask for advice before really tearing into it...

Part of the app has an area of text that needs to be formatted in a manner where there will be a description of an item in bold, followed by one or more detail items:

**Item Description:** Item Detail 1. Item Detail 2. Item Detail N.

In most cases these items will require multiple lines, so word wrapping will be necessary.

The the user will be able to tap on any bolded item description to expose a popover with options they can select that will populate the plain item details.

I was about to attempt doing this with a webview, to be able to format the text, provide natural word wrapping and use hyperlinks to call methods, etc... As I look into this more, I can see it will be a pretty weighty task and want to make sure there aren't alternatives to this before I head down what looks like a fairly long, dark tunnel.

I'm still fairly new to iOS dev, so bear with me if I come back with "noob" questions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative is [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) but it is a fairly long, dark tunnel, too.

Comment: So I see... Thanks for the pointer. Looks like I'll be reading for most of tomorrow! I'll circle back around to this soon.

Comment: I've been poking around at info on Core Text, but I'm not seeing any indication that individual sections of text can be made interactive. The base description states that Core Text is used for "laying out text and handling fonts". Am I correct in assuming that there's no facility to add an action to a run of text?

Comment: Nothing's automatic but at least Core Text gives you the ability to determine where in a string a tap happened (though you'd have to code it yourself). With a tap location, iterate over all `CTLine` objects to determine in what line the tap happened, then call `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()` to get the exact position of the tap inside the string. You would then examine the attributes of the string at that location and use them to determine what action to invoke.

Comment: Thanks Ole. That gives me hope. It looks like I may not be developing this portion of the app at this point, but at least I'll be armed if that should change.